# Add s curve to r ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to add a s curve shape to my plot to show as that is the expected pattern for my data. Currently, the function I am using shows an exponential trend and I am not sure how to change it to an s shaped curve. I'm not attached to ggplot if there is an easier way to do it.

An example of my data can be found below:

```
 > dput(data)
    structure(list(Option = c("A", "B", "C", 
    "D", "E"), x = c(104.779006457829, 172.761601935774, 
    311.687398375491, 401.963049429999, 280.432949283813), y = c(105.184639466353, 
    156.471437344915, 336.078458285771, 580.950160779444, 322.524070479162
    )), row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
    ))
```

Current code can be found below as well.

```
f <- function(x,a,b) {a * exp(b * x)}

fm_lm <- lm(log(y) ~ (x), data)
st <- list(a = exp(coef(fm_lm)[1]), b = coef(fm_lm)[2])
nls(y ~ f(x, a, b), data, start = st)

fm <- nls(y ~ f(x,a,b), data, start = c(a=62.272086, b=0.005559)) 

p2 <- ggplot(data, aes(x = x, y = y, )) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_smooth(data= data,method = "nls", se = FALSE,
              formula = y ~ f(x, a, b),
              method.args = list(start = coef(fm),algorithm="port"))

p2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this working? I used the `geom_sigmoid` function from `ggbump` package (documentation https://rdrr.io/github/davidsjoberg/ggbump/man/geom_sigmoid.html)

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggbump)
data =structure(list(Option = c("A", "B", "C", 
                              "D", "E"), x = c(104.779006457829, 172.761601935774, 
                                               311.687398375491, 401.963049429999, 280.432949283813), y = c(105.184639466353, 
                                                                                                            156.471437344915, 336.078458285771, 580.950160779444, 322.524070479162
                                               )), row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
                                               ))
f <- function(x,a,b) {a * exp(b * x)}

fm_lm <- lm(log(y) ~ (x), data)
st <- list(a = exp(coef(fm_lm)[1]), b = coef(fm_lm)[2])
nls(y ~ f(x, a, b), data, start = st)

fm <- nls(y ~ f(x,a,b), data, start = c(a=62.272086, b=0.005559)) 

p2 <- ggplot(data, aes(x = x, y = y, xend=max(data$x),yend= max(data$y))) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_smooth(data= data,method = "nls", se = FALSE,
              formula = y ~ f(x, a, b),
              method.args = list(start = coef(fm),algorithm="port"))+
  geom_sigmoid(data=data,aes(x = min(data$x),xend=max(data$x), y = min(data$y),yend= max(data$y)))

p2
```

output:

[image]

Comment: This is really useful and getting to close to what I had in my mind. Do you know if there is a way to get it run closer to the data points provided? I've tweaked the formula you've provided to start it from 0,0.

Comment: I'm not sure it is possible with this ```geom_sigmoid``` function unless you do as  you mentioned, playing with stop and start. Moreover, due to the low number of points, I think it might be kind of hard to fully adjust the curve to points' behavior

Comment: I think the best way is to set ```x = 50,xend=500```in the ```aes``` section of ```geom_sigmoid```. Try and tell me if it's better